# Can not access the windows opened by click hyperlink

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

when i access the firefox multiple window object use `require("sdk/windows").browserWindows`.
it's successful if i open new window by click Firefox binary again,but i can't access the opened window if the window is opened by click a hyperlink like this:[image]

Who can help me?

Comment: You need to listen to new windows opening. The SDK has something like this, called windowListener I think.